# appendChild recursive javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>

const div = document.createElement('div');
const div1 = document.createElement('div');
const div2 = document.createElement('div');
const div3 = document.createElement('div');

div1.appendChild(div2);
div2.appendChild(div3);
div.appendChild(div1);
```

I need a recursive function where I can create multiple divs inside another div

Where I don't have to do it manually

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly use a recursive function for this, although a simple loop would also work.

```js
function nested(name, level = 1) {
  const el = document.createElement(name);
  if (level > 1) el.append(nested(name, level - 1));
  return el;
}
const div = nested('div', 4);
console.log(div.outerHTML);
document.body.append(div);
```

```css
div { border: 1px solid; padding: 5px; }
```